# pyspark: keep a function in the lambda expression

Tags: python, apache-spark, addition, pyspark

I have the following working code:

```
def replaceNone(row):
  myList = []
  row_len = len(row)
  for i in range(0, row_len):
    if row[i] is None:
      myList.append("")
    else:
      myList.append(row[i])
  return myList

rdd_out = rdd_in.map(lambda row : replaceNone(row))
```

Here `row` is `from pyspark.sql import Row`

However, it is kind of lengthy and ugly. Is it possible to avoid making the `replaceNone` function by writing everything in the lambda process directly? Or at least simplify replaceNone()? Thanks!

Comment: generally I'd say it sounds like you want your [code reviewed](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) but this is easily solved with a simple [ternary expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) and list comprehension.

Comment: ... what does that have to do with anything I said or mentioned in the answer you have received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your goal is. It seems like you're jsut trying to replace all the `None` values in each row in `rdd_in` with empty strings, in which case you can use a list comprehension:

`rdd_out = rdd_in.map(lambda row: [r if r is not None else "" for r in row])`

The first call to map will make a new list for every element in `row` and the list comprehension will replace all `None`s with empty strings.

This worked on a trivial example (and defined map since it's not defined for a list):

```
def map(l, f):
    return [f(r) for r in l]

l = [[1,None,2],[3,4,None],[None,5,6]]
l2 = map(l, lambda row: [i if i is not None  else "" for i in row])

print(l2)
>>> [[1, '', 2], [3, 4, ''], ['', 5, 6]]
```

Comment: what do you mean "map is not defined for a list"? the built in `map` takes the callable as the first argument and the sequence as the second, just swap the order of the arguments and you don't need to redefine it.

Comment: It is a bit tricky as the Row element can not be reassigned, row[i] = "" won't work.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I forgot that there was a built-in general map. Since you can't call `[1,2,3].map()` I (stupidly) just made a new function.

Comment: @zephyr1999: how would I use the your map function on rdd_in? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame you don't need to. I only used it because I didn't want to go through the effort of setting up an RDD for testing. You should be able to use the `rdd_out = ...` line of code in my answer in place of your entire code block.

Comment: @Edamame you may want to look into how [rows are stored in pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row) for efficiency. I don't have much experience in that specifically, so unless the RDDs automatically convert lists, you may be loosing some of the in-memory advantages by converting to a list, as my code does.